# Polymorphism - Spring java services and controllers

Tags: java, spring, polymorphism

In my project i have some class hierarchy for tasks:

```
         BaseTask

      /            \ 
CriticalTask         MarginalTask
```

I have the following service:

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class TaskService implements ITaskService  {

   public void execute(CriticalTask  task) {
      ...
   }

   public void execute(MarginalTask task) {
      ...
   }
}
```

I would like to have the following controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/executeTask", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public void executeTask(@RequestBody BaseTaskDTO baseTaskDTO , HttpServletRequest request) {

    this.taskService.execute(baseTaskDTO);

}
```

and i would like this service to actually call the "execute" method with the corresponding task.

too bad this is not working.

I know polymorphism can help me on this goal, i.e. all the tasksDTOs can implement the "execute" method and then i simply call the baseTask.execute().
The problem with this is that it feels really awkward to put some logic inside the DTO (were only data should be exists and nothing else)

Are there any good practices to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could think about a `TaskExecutor`, that will be responsible to execute your task and a `Map<Class<?>,TaskExecutor>` that will be a field in `TaskService` and will be used to fetch the right `TaskExecutor` to execute a given task.

In your service you could have (among other methods) something like:

```
@Override
public void execute(TaskDTO task) {
    taskExecutors.get(task.getClass()).execute(task);
}
```

this would imply that you will need all DTO classes you want to execute declared in that map with a given `TaskExecutor` associated.

You controller will just parse it to the right DTO object, and give to the `TaskService`, that will define the best `TaskExecutor` to perform the execution. `execute` method will be invoked and will invoke with that DTO as parameter. One possible `TaskExecutor` definition would be something like:

```
public interface TaskExecutor {

    void execute(TaskDTO taskDTO);

}
```

at the end you will have one execute method in `TaskService` but different implementation of `TaskExecutor`, that will handle specific `TaskDTO` implementations. This uses some concepts of [Strategy Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

**This will solve your requirement in which the execution method should be decopled from the DTO itself.**

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't even compile indeed as the dynamic polymorphism is for method calls, not for parameters. Here you are calling an overloaded method that does not exist.
A simple "hack" could be:

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class TaskService implements ITaskService  {

    public void execute(BaseTask task){
      if( task instanceof CriticalTask){
         execute((CriticalTask) task);
      else
         execute((MarginalTask) task);
    }

    void execute(CriticalTask  task) {
      ...
    }

    void execute(MarginalTask task) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: the instanceof is exactly what i'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you are doing things backwards. The `Task` should know what it does and how it does it. It should have a `run` or `execute` method (like `Runnable`). Your `TaskService` then only needs to invoke that method on the given argument

```
public void execute(BaseTask task) { // <-- doesn't matter what implementation it is
    task.execute();
}
```

That's where polymorphism comes into play.

Comment: My problem is that the task is an entity. and i dont want to put business logic inside an entity  (an entity as far as i concerned is all about fields and setters \ getters - pojo) dont you agree?

Comment: @Urbanleg Yes and no. In that case, you'll probably want a factory (like some other answers suggest) that generates something that can be executed.